# How to add a Multi-pick list field on Task object in Lightning Experience

Tags: page-layout, tasks

The task I'm creating is a related list of opportunity. I have already added the field in page layout of Task, but it is not visible. Only if I edit the task I could see the Multi-pick list field.

So, how can I display a Multi-pick list on the Activity page as shown in the image.[image: ABC is a Opportunity]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you added the field in a specific section on the page layout and that the section is visible only on edit? You may like to verify that.

Comment: Ya. I have only one section i.e, Task section. All the fields are visible there. Even Multi-pick list field is available there. But I can't see that field on the Activity Page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publisher view in the Activity component is controlled by the "New Task" action layout, not the Task or Event page layout.

If this is an object-specific action, the layout can be edited in Object Manager for the Opportunity, under Buttons, Links and Actions. If this is a global action, the action layout can be edited in Global Actions in Setup. In either case, you'd click into the action itself and then click the Edit Layout button.

You can tell which it type of action this is by viewing the page layout for the Opportunity, navigating to the Lightning and Mobile Actions section, and hovering over the icon for the action in the page layout field navigator. If the hover name starts with "Opportunity", it is an object-specific action.

Comment: Thank you so much @David Reed. The solution you gave worked for my scenario.